# confusion with function parameters and why you do not need to call the parameter by its name

Tags: python, function, parameters, scope

first of all, i am using Python3

i was going through Khanacademy's Python tutorial about functions:

[Defining a Factorial Function](http://www.khanacademy.org/science/computer-science/v/defining-a-factorial-function)

Here is the code:

```
def factorial(number):
    product = 1
    for i in range(number):
        product = product * (i+1)
    return product

user_input = int(input("enter a number that you want to factorial: "))
factorial_of_user_input = factorial(user_input)
print(factorial_of_user_input)
```

i am having a hard time explaining my confusion, so please bear with me.  i do not understand the following:  Sal named the parameter **number**.  But then, **number** vanishes.

initially, before the function tutorial, **user_input** was named **number** followed by a **print(number)**.  you get input, call it **number** then you print **number**, which made perfect sense because it is nice and consistent.

unfortunately, now, for me, that consistency is broken.  how can you change make the variable name different from the parameter name and have it work?  because consistency is broken, i figured that it would bomb-out.  in my mind, i look at it like this: the function looks for an integer in a bucket with the name of **number**.  if you do not give it an integer from that exact bucket, it just wont work - sorta like sticking a round peg into a rectangle.

what magic did Python use to figure out that **user_input** is the same thing as **number**?

Comment: This is more a conceptual problem to you I guess? If so, [read this](http://www.learningpythonprogramming.com/2010/05/creating-functions-with-parameters.html).

Comment: This is nothing particular to Python of course.

Comment: @jro - excellent find.  thank you!  it's helping out a lot.  i'm slow to understand this stuff, so i'm reading it over and over and trying to slowly process it.

Answer (score 0):

number is the name given to the `factorial` function, that's all the syntax means: You feed in a single argument, and inside the `factorial` function it becomes known as name. The name `user_input` is not relevant, you could as well write
`factorial(5)`.

This is similar in other languages. For example, in C++ you could write a function

```
int square(int input_number){ return input_number*input_number ; }
```

and you could call it by saying `square(5)`

Your view of what is going on is self-consistent but it is NOT how python or other languages work. Specifically you say *the function looks for an integer in a bucket with the name of number.*

When you declare a function like the one in your example, you say that whatever value you feed will be known, internally, as `number`. However, there IS a way to get the behaviur you expected. In python it looks like this:

```
def myfunction():
    print(some_value)
```

In this case, `some_value` will have to exist and be known by that name in the *scope* (or bucket as you called it). So, you would need to do this to make this work:

```
def myfunction():
    print(some_value)
some_value=3
myfunction()
```

As an opposite example, imagine if you would like to input a value that is not known by a specific name, you would do something like

```
def myfunction(a,b,c): 
    print(("a ",a," b ",b,"c ",c))
j=4
myfunction(1,j,5+2)
gives('a ', 1, ' b ', 4, 'c ', 7)
```

Comment: sorry, i'm still not getting it.  i am at the most basic of levels when it comes to this stuff.  i have no clue what to make of the C++ example.

you stated, "You feed in a single parameter, and the inside factorial it is called name..."

do you mean number?

also, i'm thinking that why do you have to have something in the parameter spot to begin with?  why can't you just leave it blank?  personally, that would make a bit more sense to me.

next, why won't this take my break returns?

Answer (score 0):

The `factorial` function knows nothing of what is happening outside its own code block (the indented section).  When you pass parameters into it, the names are not passed with them. All the function sees is that you have passed an integer object in. The purpose of the parentheses in the function declaration (`(number)` in this case) is to assign names to the objects that are passed into the function.

In short, while outside the function the input is known as `user_input`, it is passed as a nameless integer to the function, and the function is responsible for naming the object for itself via its definition.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to [namespaces.](http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/)

You need to understand what **scope** you are in. In python scopes are separated by functions, classes, and modules. In your case, you first need to understand the function scope.

If i have a block of code like this:

```
def function1(var1):
    print var1

var1 = 'Variable 1'
function1(var1) #will print: Variable 1
function1('var1 is just for use inside the function') #will print: var1 is just for use...
print var1 #will print: Variable 1, because we never did any assignment outside of the function
```

It shows that var1 inside the function isn't var1 outside of the function. There's namespaces called `global` and `local`. To see the variables in each one of these scopes at anytime, python has two builtin functions called `globals()` and `locals()` that will show you a dictionary(names mapped to values) of all of the variables and their values in the scope you called.